# floats in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsarray

I have an NSArray of floats which I did by encapsulating the floats using

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] ;
```

Then I passed that array somewhere else and I need to pull those floats out of the array and perform basic arithmatic. When I try

```
[myArray objectAtIndex:i] ;
```

The compiler complains that I'm trying to perform arithmatic on a type id. It also won't let me cast to float or double.

Any ideas? This seems like it should be an easy problem. Maybe it will come to me after another cup of coffee, but some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that (since Xcode 4.4) you can use the new `NSNumber` literals to initialize an `NSNumber` object with primitive types like this: `NSNumber *num = @(myFloat);`

Comment: It now seems crazy that I didn't know the answer to this just three short years ago. Thanks all for helping me in my rookie days :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unbox the floats like this:

```
float f = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Unbox the float value from the NSNumber object thusly:

```
NSNumber *number = myArray[i];
float f = [number floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are converting float value to `NSNumber` object and adding it to `NSArray`.So you have to again convert `NSNumber` object to float value.

```
NSNumber *number = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
float f = [number floatValue];
```